# Exim: исправить ошибку failed to unlink /var/spool/exim//msglog//1hppB7-00000e-O9: Permission denied

Tags: docker, доступ, exim

Настраиваю Exim на базе alpine

Запускается он так:

```
exim -bd -q5s -v
```

Конфиги не пишу, тут они имхо, не нужны.

Опция `-q5s` запускает Exim в "двойном" режиме, когда он исполняет роль MTA + проверяет очереди:

> -q
>             When a time value is present, the -q option causes Exim to
>             run as a daemon, starting a queue runner process at intervals
>             specified by the given time value. This form of the -q option
>             is commonly combined with the -bd option, in which case a
>             single daemon process handles both functions. A common way of
>             starting up a combined daemon at system boot time is to use a
>             command such as
>               /usr/exim/bin/exim -bd -q30m
>             Such a daemon listens for incoming SMTP calls, and also
>             starts a queue runner process every 30 minutes.
>             When a daemon is started by -q with a time value, but without
>             -bd, no pid file is written unless one is explicitly
>             requested by the -oP option.

Теперь в логах (пишутся в консоль) получаю такие сообщения:

```
    8 SIGALRM received
    8 1 queue-runner process running
    8 Listening...
  821 Starting queue-runner: pid 821
  821 exec /usr/sbin/exim -qG
2019-07-23 07:45:32 1hppB7-00000e-O9 failed to unlink /var/spool/exim//msglog//1hppB7-00000e-O9: Permission denied
    8 child 821 ended: status=0x0
    8   normal exit, 0
    8 0 queue-runner processes now running
    8 Listening...
```

`ls -la /var/spool/exim//msglog//1hppB7-00000e-O9`:

```
-rw-r-----    1 exim     exim         64052 Jul 23 08:28 /var/spool/exim//msglog//1hppB7-00000e-O9
```

Если запускать `/usr/sbin/exim -qG` от root, та же самая ошибка:

```
2019-07-23 08:28:49 1hppB7-00000e-O9 failed to unlink /var/spool/exim//msglog//1hppB7-00000e-O9: Permission denied
```

`ls -la /usr/sbin/exim`:

```
-rwsr-xr-x    1 root     root       1141696 May 10 10:33 /usr/sbin/exim
```

то есть установлен `SGID`

```
exim --version
Exim version 4.92 #4 built 10-May-2019 10:33:31
```

Почему возникает такая странная ошибка, и что с ней делать? Даже не могу понять, в какую сторону копать.

PS. Есть сделать `chmod 777 этот-файл`, права сбрасываются обратно (экзимом), проблема остается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было выставить правильно владельца: поменять `root.mail` на `exim.mail`:

```
chown exim.mail /var/spool/mail /var/mail /var/spool/exim /var/spool/exim/db /var/spool/exim/input /var/spool/exim/msglog
```

хотя довольно странно, `/var/spool/exim/msglog` имел права на запись группы `mail`, в которой состоит Exim